# Jquery - Javascript, checked checkbox by value which is the value is part of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of checkbox which is have value like this

```
<input  name="selection[]" value="2282,2283,2284,2285,2286,2287,2288,2289,2290,2298,2299,2300" type="checkbox">

<input name="selection[]" value="1429,1432,1450,1451,1462,1469" type="checkbox">

<input name="selection[]" value="667,669,679,683,685,686,687" type="checkbox">
```

If I have an array like this named temp whic is have data like this:

```
Array [ 2282, 2283, 2284, 2285, 2286, 2287, 2288, 2289, 2290, 2298, 2299 , 2300 ]
```

How can I checked the checkbox with have value stringify of this array, which is in my case is the first checkbox  ?

So far, this is my code :

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function(data){
       var temp = $('#print-sticker-keren').attr('data-print').split(',').map(Number);            
      // THis is the array : Array [ 2282, 2283, 2284, 2285, 2286, 2287, 2288, 2289, 2290, 2298, 2299 , 2300 ]


        for (i=0; i!=temp.length;i++) {
            var checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='"+temp[i]+"']");
            checkbox.attr("checked","checked");
        }

    });
```

Please advise

Updated Answerd.

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function(data){
        var temp = $('#print-sticker-keren').attr('data-print').split(',').map(Number);
        var checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='selection[]']");


        for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
            var coba = $(checkbox[i]).val().split(',').map(Number); // checkbox[i].val is not a function

            for (var j = 0; j < coba.length; j++) {
               var ins = $.inArray(coba[j], temp);

               if(ins !== -1){
                   $(checkbox[i]).attr("checked","checked");
               }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Seems both uneccessary and like a very bad idea, to use values like that to match up an element

Comment: You are creating `tempString` by joining stuff with a comma, and then in the next line you split it at the comma again - what’s the purpose of that redundancy?

Comment: Are you looking for the checkbox that has _all_ those values, in the exact same order? Then why a loop in the first place, that could be done in one go.

Comment: @ Cbroe, Thanks for redundancy alert. I edited my code

Comment: @CBroe in the exact same order

Comment: `var temp = $('#print-sticker-keren').attr('data-print');` and `var checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='"+temp+"']");` should be enough to select the element that has the _exact_ value attribute set in the HTML.